# How to dynamically change background-image css properties with active storage

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I use:

```
<%=image_tag(url_for(object.image)%>
```

to place the image url on each object

```
<div class='bg' style="background:url('img.jpg')"></div>
```

I use rails active storage. I tried this:

```
<div "style="background: url(<%=image_tag(@object.image)%>">
```

but the image is not rendered. Here is the HTML output:

```
<div style="background: url(<img src=" http:="" localhost:3000="" rails="" active_storage="" blobs="" eyjfcmfpbhmionsibwvzc2fnzsi6ikjbahbhdz09iiwizxhwijpudwxslcjwdxiioijibg9ix2lkin19--45640b74829f35f71ed0d53b6c237f5257810f29="" beer_lager_bg.jpg"="">
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case you just need to put:

```
<div class='bg' style="background: url(<%= url_for(object.image) %>) no-repeat;"></div>
```

Remember: CSS isn't HTML, the image_helper will create a `<img>` tag, and you don't need that for CSS (`style="..."`)!

But the right way to do this is:

```
*.css - *.scss
.bg {
  /* The image used */                 /*accepts a full URL*/ 
  background-image: asset_path(url_for(object.image));}
```

More in here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path

Comment: I need a dynamic background image  that will change depending on the present object

Comment: Every time you update this image when someone accesses your page will render this new image, what you want to say with: "dynamic background"?

Comment: I did this as you requested `<div class='col-sm-12' style="background: url(<%= url_for(@product.image) %>) no-repeat;"></div>` but no image i displayed.  The instance variable is `@product` Here is the html output, `<div class="col-sm-12" style="background: url(/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBHdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--45640b74829f35f71ed0d53b6c237f5257810f29/beer_lager_bg.jpg) no-repeat;"></div>.` The image is beer_lager_bg.jpg but it has a  string of letters before it as you can see.